# What is the thinking behind letting unprofitable corporates list on an exchange?

Tags: stock-markets, stock-exchanges, ipo

I read somewhere that 2021 set a record in terms of the number of unprofitable new listings on the exchanges (revenue but no earnings). To verify, I looked up some of the listing requirements and saw that most of criteria concern market cap. The requirements around income statements do seem rather lax:

[image]

If we take a historical perspective, an IPO decades ago was more about expansion / scaling up. The profitability of the company was a non-factor. Presumably, the founders had already de-risked the business model. Of course, there are no guarantees about which way the market is headed tomorrow, but still, if the company never does demonstrate positive earnings after years and years, it's not just systematic risk anymore. It seems to me that allowing listings whose earnings are so abstract and future-dependent would just increase idiosyncratic risk and potentially harmful for retail investors.

### Question

Is there substance to these concerns or is there a more benign explanation?

Comment: Whether the concern is meaningful is entirely subjective.  Circumstances shift over time and many companies in the past that couldn't meet the NYSE's stringent rules wound up on NASDAQ or other OTC marketplaces.  Some of those companies, such as Amazon.com, Inc. and Amgen, Inc., became great enterprises thus prodding the NYSE to change some of its requirements in order to remain competitive.  Whether that's concerning seems subjective.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Companies need money to expand and grow their business, and IPO is a way for companies to raise that money from the general public. This is compared to private funding where specific investors have a chance to invest in the company under specific terms and conditions (in startup world - "rounds" with various hedge funds and venture capitalists).

There's absolutely no requirement for a company to be profitable before offering its shares on a public exchange. "Public" on these exchanges is not limited to retail investors. It includes mutual funds, investment firms, pension funds, insurance companies, and basically any investor, not just mom and pop. For all these investors (and for moms and pops), IPOs are the only way to invest in these companies, why should they be denied access?

Companies are under no obligation to limit their funding to private investors during their startup and growth stage until profitability. Technically, nothing prevents you from listing a brand new company with no products or revenue, as long as you're compliant with all the SEC requirements. There's no requirement for angel investors or VC rounds, but it is usually easier (and significantly cheaper) for startups at their first steps to raise money from private investors than from public listing.

The public doesn't have to buy what's offered in the IPO. If the company isn't profitable, if the business model is questionable, if the product doesn't look like it has a reasonable future - the public won't buy. There have in fact been failed IPOs (Uber is a good example).

Answer (score 1):

I suggest a reframing of what you view as the purpose / benefit of publicly traded companies:

**Reframing #1:** *"Presumably, the founders had already de-risked the business model."*

Why would you presume this? If the business was 'de-risked', why wouldn't the original founders simply seek lower-cost debt for example in the bond market, who would expect less compensation in exchange for a 'surer' thing? The answer is truly that equity is sought mostly *when risk still exists*! Truly the main function of a stock exchange is to allow risk to be 'sold' from those who have too much, to those who desire more in exchange for higher returns.

**Reframing #2**: *"It seems to me that allowing listings whose earnings are so abstract and future-dependent would just increase idiosyncratic risk and potentially harmful for retail investors."*

Rather, consider that the fundemental benefit of being a public company is **precisely** that you have access to a wide pool of funds from individuals who collectively can take on risk at a combined scale that allows the funding of uncertain projects.

A common example is that many railroads were fundamentally uncertain ventures, not universally supported at the time by governments [who would be the only single entities wealthy enough to afford their financing]. Their creation was only possible by pooling risk through public companies funded by individual investors. Some of these corporations failed, and some laid the foundation for infrastructure that remains critical today. Similarly, most new tech companies at a stage of IPO are also at critical stages of needing initial funding for something that might pay off well, and might otherwise turn to nothing.

You imply in your question that risk is not appropriate for 'retail investors', and to that I have 2 points:

(1) It is not the role of the exchange itself to 'protect' a retail investor from themselves [although some governments may put limits on who can invest in what method, because part of a government's role may include individual protection, but that isn't really the concern of the exchange as a private entity itself].

(2) Investing in IPO's in on the higher end of equity risk, and in order to suffer that risk, you really would need to seek it out. Many retail investors do seek that risk; sometimes to their detriment, and sometimes to their benefit.